# Floating divs glitch on resize in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Does anyone know how to fix this problem. The only browser that works correctly is Firefox; in Chrome and Edge it doesn't work. When I resize the screen the box changes the position. Is there some solution?

Screenshot

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="box" style="background:#F00; height:200px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:#F0F; width:25%"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:#FF0; width:25%"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:#00F; width:25%"></div>
<div class="box" style="background:#55F; width:25%"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).resize(resize)

function resize() {
  $(".box").each(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).width() * 0.5)
  });
}
```

Here's the Codepen link:
http://codepen.io/Tufik/pen/rxyQmV

UPDATE---------

I modified the CodePen to show a more complex structure. The problem is when you resize the screen browser, the divs don't respect the correct position, some divs jump to the next line.

This is an old problem. I think it's because HTML is not pixel perfect. But I want to know if there is some easy solution different to use masonry.js or any plugins. Firefox work great, but Chrome or Edge not.

Comment: It works fine with Safari for me.

Comment: Same with Chrome, go on and throw it trough [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/).

Comment: Not working good on my chrome

Comment: A cleaner version of the problem (easier to see what's going on) is here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/nq5ct2y2/)

Comment: Hi, the JSFiddle show the same problem.... When you resize the Browser window slowly. The boxs grid don't work correctly in some sizes... I think it is because Chrome don't work with decimal values...... Some solution without use masonry.js

Comment: @TufikChediak Yes, it's a better version of your problem (your CSS is extremely badly put together, making it harder to see what's going on).

Comment: Ok, i modified the CodePen to show a more complex structure... The problem is my Grid when i float it. When you are resize the screen browser, don't respect the correct position... some divs jump to the next line.

Comment: @TufikChediak You are correct when you say "I think it because HTML is not pixel pefect". [See my answer for a pixel perfect solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34662464/2502532).

Comment: Mmmmmm, i will continue using jquery.packery.js until Chrome And Edge fixed this problem,,,, At less Firefox work great.... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem: Unpredictable browser rounding of integers

Each browser calculates numbers differently. For widths and heights, the browser also rounds to the nearest integer for layout. So, the computed pixel-width of each floated box may have a different initial value after converting from percentage and filling out the container. Calculating on these numbers can lead to unpredictable results.

Here is an example of how the values are being calculated in your setup (resize the browser and watch the values change):

```js
function resize() {
  $(".box").each(function() {
    var height = $(this).width() * 0.5;
    $(this)
      .height(height)
      .html("<code>height: " + $(this).height() + "px (rounded from " + height + ")</code>");
  });
}

$(window).resize(resize);
resize();
```

```css
.box { float: left; }
.box-large {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
.box-small {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box-large" style="background:#F00;"></div>
<div class="box box-small" style="background:#F0F;"></div>
<div class="box box-small" style="background:#FF0;"></div>
<div class="box box-small" style="background:#00F;"></div>
<div class="box box-small" style="background:#55F;"></div>
```

### Solution: uniformly apply your own rounded integer

One way to solve this is to create your own new height value, round it to a whole integer and apply it uniformly to each box instead of applying the decimal value and relying on the browser to do the rounding. The best way to do this is to calculate the new height value from one box and apply it to the others, instead of doing a calculation on each.

Because you have two different sized boxes, we do this calculation twice: once for the large box and once for the small box. The calculated large height value gets applied to all large boxes (only one in this case) and the calculated small height value gets applied to all small boxes.

Example:

```js
function resize() {
  var $larges  = $('.box-large'),   // Get all large boxes
      $lgFirst = $($larges.get(0)), // Get first large box
      lgHeight = Math.floor(        // Round down before the browser screws it up
        $lgFirst.width() / 2        // Calculate new height
      ),
      $smalls  = $('.box-small'),   // Get all small boxes
      $smFirst = $($smalls.get(0)), // Get first small box
      smHeight = Math.floor(        // Round down before the browser screws it up
        $smFirst.width() / 2        // Calculate new height
      ),
      
      // Function returns a function to keep things DRY
      setHeight = function(height) {
        
        // This function is returned to the .each() call later
        return function () {
          $(this)
            .height(height)
            .html("<code>height: " + height + "px</code>"); 
        }
      };
  
  // Set height of all large boxes to new large height
  $larges.each(setHeight(lgHeight));
  
  // Set height of all small boxes to new small height
  $smalls.each(setHeight(smHeight));
}

$(window).resize(resize);
resize();
```

```css
.box { float: left; }
.box-large {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
.box-small {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box-large" style="background:#F00;"></div>
<div class="box box-small" style="background:#F0F;"></div>
<div class="box box-small" style="background:#FF0;"></div>
<div class="box box-small" style="background:#00F;"></div>
<div class="box box-small" style="background:#55F;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you... I will continue using jquery.packery.js until Chrome And Edge fixed this problem,,,, At less Firefox work great.... :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this answers your question, but I think css flex box is what you are looking for. you don't need javascript to do this.

The below code will align your divs all in one line and also provides responsiveness using flex box(Not exact layout you are looking but im sure you will be able to figure it out)

For more info please refer this [article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            height: 200px;
            flex-grow: 1
        }

        .column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-grow: 1
        }

        .big {
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="big" style="background:#F00;">
                1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="big" style="background:#F0F;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="big" style="background:#00F;">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="big " style="background:#FF0; ">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="big" style="background:#55F;">
                5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? If you could comment on why then it will help me in improving the answer ??

Comment: Maybe it's because your code produces this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/7tt1ppak/)?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Thanks. I did mention the answer may not be the exact layout that OP wants and it would be fairly simple to improvise by reading the article. Anyhow i have updated my answer with exact layout

Comment: Your solution still doesn't do what the OP wants (not even close). You could replicate what you've produced without flexboxes (or js) so it's very unclear how you think they'll help in this situation -- and I really don't think they will. It's also not a good answer to say: "Read this article". Such a thing is highly discouraged here.